# How to force PHP set correct permissions on files uploading?

Tags: php, permissions, apache2, freebsd, patch

I have server with FreeBSD 8.0, Apache 2.2.23 and PHP 5.4.10. That is my VirtualHost config:

```
<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName site.com
    ServerAlias www.site.com
    DocumentRoot /usr/home/site/pub/htdocs/
    php_admin_value open_basedir /usr/home/site/
    php_admin_value session.save_path 0;0660;/usr/home/site/pub/tmp/
    php_admin_value upload_tmp_dir /usr/home/site/pub/tmp/
</VirtualHost>
```

/usr/home/site/pub/tmp/ owned by site:www with 4770 permission. Session files creating correctly (660 and site:www). But uploaded temporary files creating with 600 in permissions. So, because this temporary file owned by site:www and Apache running from www:www, move_uploaded_file() cannot move file.

How to fix it?

I think that I need patch PHP for force set permission on this tmp file. But where? And which internal function in PHP can to do it?

Comment: This function cannot help, because file owned by site:www with 600 and Apache running from www:www.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've find the way to fix it. That is code of my patch:

```
*** main/php_open_temporary_file.c.orig 2013-01-11 20:33:42.000000000 +0400
--- main/php_open_temporary_file.c  2013-01-11 21:17:44.000000000 +0400
***************
*** 101,113 ****
    char cwd[MAXPATHLEN];
    cwd_state new_state;
    int fd = -1;
! #ifndef HAVE_MKSTEMP
!   int open_flags = O_CREAT | O_TRUNC | O_RDWR
! #ifdef PHP_WIN32
!       | _O_BINARY
! #endif
!       ;
! #endif

    if (!path || !path[0]) {
        return -1;
--- 101,107 ----
    char cwd[MAXPATHLEN];
    cwd_state new_state;
    int fd = -1;
!   int open_flags = O_CREAT | O_TRUNC | O_RDWR;

    if (!path || !path[0]) {
        return -1;
***************
*** 144,169 ****
        return -1;
    }

- #ifdef PHP_WIN32
- 
-   if (GetTempFileName(new_state.cwd, pfx, 0, opened_path)) {
-       /* Some versions of windows set the temp file to be read-only,
-        * which means that opening it will fail... */
-       if (VCWD_CHMOD(opened_path, 0600)) {
-           efree(opened_path);
-           free(new_state.cwd);
-           return -1;
-       }
-       fd = VCWD_OPEN_MODE(opened_path, open_flags, 0600);
-   }
- 
- #elif defined(HAVE_MKSTEMP)
-   fd = mkstemp(opened_path);
- #else
    if (mktemp(opened_path)) {
!       fd = VCWD_OPEN(opened_path, open_flags);
    }
- #endif

    if (fd == -1 || !opened_path_p) {
        efree(opened_path);
--- 138,146 ----
        return -1;
    }

    if (mktemp(opened_path)) {
!       fd = VCWD_OPEN_MODE(opened_path, open_flags, 0660);
    }

    if (fd == -1 || !opened_path_p) {
        efree(opened_path);
```

Now it working fine, but show the warning "Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Operation not permitted in /path/to/script.php on line 111". How to suppress this warning - I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Create the file and then set the permission would work.

```
chmod("/somedir/yourfile", 0644);
```

Comment: This function cannot help, because file owned by site:www with 600 and Apache running from www:www.

Answer (score 0):

Don't downvote peole who are telling you to use `chmod()` because that is the *only solution* to change file permissions from PHP. However, the main problem appears to be that either Apache is creating the files with a different uid than what the script is running as, [not likely AFAIK] or you're trying to modify files that were created using a different process running as a different user.

Only the owner of the file can change permission/ownership on a file, and unless a separate process ran specifically to transfer ownership to another uid the owner of the file is the uid that created it.

Once again, `chmod()` and `chown()` are the *only two methods* by which you can change permissions and ownership, and are equivalent to issuing the shell commands via `exec()`.

Comment: I'm sorry, but that is not my downvoting. Yes, you're right. But sessions files creating correctly. So, PHP can set permissions force. Now I think I have to patch php_open_temporary_file.c.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at `chown` you can change the owner of the file temporarily so you can make appropriate changes:

```
$File = '/path/to/file';
chown($File, USERNAMEPHPISRUNNIGNAT);
chmod($File, 0644);
// Makes Appropriate changes To Files 
chown($File, originalowner);
// Changes your file back to it's original owner
```

Want to find out what username php is running as:

`echo exec('whoami');`

The above will return the user which php is running as.